# Can you only read the al-Fatihah in any prayer and rakaat?

Tags: salat, quran-recitation, surat-al-fatihah

So,sometimes I want to do a sunnah prayer but the problem is that I have no time. Even if I do,it's not very long. So,I always think to myself "Can I do it without reading the extra surah after the al-Fatihah? Is it allowed? Will Allah accept it?". Finally,I've found this website and I hope this will help me.

Comment: Praying is a duty for every Muslim saying you don't have time for that already is sinful because prayer is the most important worship as it is a daily duty with specific timings that one is ordered to respect. Anything else in this life is compared to that of no value, as nothing should hinder you from obeying Allah. See also https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/51361/13438 and https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/49489/can-you-read-sura-fatihah-after-the-fatihah-in-salaah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to recite an extra surah other than Fathihah for prayers. But you dont need to do a long surah, why not a single verse from Ikhlaas or Naas.

We can recite verse 2:255 but not 112:1? Both are single verse but only size differs. So if you dont have time, just recite a single line of a surah and that will be enough.

Answer (score 0):

According to some scholars, if you choose to read a surah after Surat al Fatihah, you must read at least 3 verses, or 1 verse which is equivalent to 3 verses.

You may read only surah Fatihah, then move on to rukoo, but ask yourself this:
Do you love Allah enough to omit 1 surah, after al Fatihah, when, from my experience, a very few amount of Muslims omit reading a surah after reciting al Fatihah?

Be a good example to all Muslims.

Proof from Sunnah:

https://sunnah.com/muslim/4/45
https://sunnah.com/muslim/4/46

Assalam u Alaykum WaramatUllahi Wabarakatuhu

Comment: Try to bring on more evidence to back up your answer