# can we repeat surah fatia 2 times in one rakat

Tags: salat, surat-al-fatihah

can we recite surah Fatiha 2 rimes in on Rakat. one after another like first we recite surah Fatiha and then instead of reciting another surah like surah ikhlas we recite surah Fatiha again because we can recite any surah from the Quran

Comment: I've answered this question already, See [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/49489/13438).